# In Pandas can I get the index number of the first match?

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
df['col1']

0                company_id
1     current_value scope 1
2     current_value scope 2
3     current_value scope 3
4                      Name
5                    Intuit
6                       NaN
7                       NaN
8              PROJECT DATA
9                      Name
10                      NaN
11                      NaN
12                      NaN
13                      NaN
14                      NaN
Name: Url, dtype: object
```

Can I figure out what the index of the first instance of "name" is, in this case it would be 4? I tried:

```
df[['column1'=="Name"]].index[0]
```

but I'm getting

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 15.
```

Comment: @enke Thank you, it worked. Can you put that as a answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because `['col1'=='Name']` returns `[False]` and since the length of `df` is 15, you can't filter it with a list of length 1 (the length of the boolean mask has to be the same as the length of the DataFrame/Series).

You could create a boolean mask by:

```
msk = df['col1'].eq('Name')
```

Then you could use the `idxmax` method:

```
out = msk.idxmax()
```

Alternatively, you could use `msk` to filter `df` or its index:

```
idx = df.index[msk]
```

This returns an IntIndex object of length 2 (since there are 2 "Name"s in "col1"). Then to get the first, you can index it:

```
out = idx[0]
```